# Upgrade openssl in apache from source and set as default

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ssl, apache-2.4, openssl

I have upgraded the openssl from source to version OpenSSL 1.0.1s for Apache, which installed under /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl, and change the symlink to point it into this new installation directory and run the below command.

```
$openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1s  1 Mar 2016
```

It is showing the new upgraded version, But while using php or checking in phpinfo() it is still showing the old version.

phpinfo():

```
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
Openssl default config  /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
```

Please suggest me how to make this new version effective in all the places, I also have ssl installed on my site do I also need to Regenerate the CSR and Private Key and re-issue the ssl certificate.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See for instance [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/669510/37681) but mentioning which OS (and or distro) you run might be useful too...

Comment: It's under amazon linux